# ios how can my app go back to the first screen?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to have a home button, so the user can go to the first screen.  On my old xcode I stored the home `Viewcontroller` in a global and used the following code

```
-(IBAction) aHome: (id) sender
{
    [ mHomeController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: true];
    [mHomeController.view addSubview: mHomeController->adView];
}
```

I know get a error saying adView does not exist.  How can I do this in the new xcode?

Comment: Do you use storyboard? If yes, look at `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Comment: If you use xib files the use `popToRootViewController` of `navigationController`

Comment: Please take out time and edit your question with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the top of your navigation controller's stack, which is your root view controller, than you can use the following line of code.

```
- (IBAction)goHome:(id)sender { 
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
 }
```

Comment: This takes me back to the navigation controller's root view (as expected), but how do I get back to the launch view controller?